# Link directives in Rst grammar

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils, doi

How can I link directive with :doi: or :arxiv: in Rst.

I'm making a document with Rst, but when I try to link with arxiv, it shows broken link.

What I tried is below but not working.

```
<:doi:`10.1145/2487575.2487591>`
```

or

```
:arxiv:`1309.0238`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doi` example can be addressed by using the [extlinks](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html) Sphinx extension, by adding these contents to `conf.py`:

```
extlinks = {
    'doi': ('https://dx.doi.org/%s', 'doi:'),
}
```

([Source](https://gist.github.com/jonls/b910afc46473b02597c4#gistcomment-1986251))

And for `arxiv`, something similar.

---

For a more generic case, you would need to either

1. create a "custom role", see for example https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html (this tutorial creates a custom directive, but it should be similar), or
2. find a Sphinx extension that already does it for you.